# clone a row inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with just one row and I want to add the other rows dynamicly so obviesley I am using the function clone() so here is the code

```
    <table>
    <th>New SL</th>
    <th>condition</th>
    <th>Sl donne</th>
    <div id="conditions" numTypes="0">
      <div class="condition clone" id="lol">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <select id="cond[0][new]" class="select-attribut">
              <% @attribut.each do |att| %>
                  <option id="<%= att.id %>"><%= att.nom %></option>
              <% end %>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <select id="cond[0][operation]" class="select-operation">
              <% @operation_attribut.each do |op| %>
                  <option id="<%= op.id %>"><%= op.nom %></option>
              <% end %>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <select id="cond[0][old]" class="select-attribut">
              <% @attribut.each do |att| %>
                  <option id="<%= att.id %>"><%= att.nom %></option>
              <% end %>
            </select>

          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="cond[0][tr_condition]" class="tr_condition">
          <td>
            <select id="cond[0][op_condition]" class="select-operation">
              <% @operation_condition.each do |att| %>
                  <option id="<%= att.id %>"><%= att.nom %></option>
              <% end %>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </div>

      <tr id="add">
        <td align="left">
          <button class="btn green plus-cond"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
```

just ignore the <%%> its ruby on rails it is just to fill the option

and here is the Jquery code

```
   $(".plus-cond").bind("click",function(){
        group = $(".clone").clone();

        $("#add").before(group);
});
```

but when I am testing it the variable group it contains only the parent div without its children

Comment: divs cannot be children of table elements

Comment: @Pete thanks for the tip I didn't khnow that I chnaged it and it works